# How do I exit the program when i type "q" or "Q"

Tags: arrays, exit

I would like to know how you terminate the program when typing "q" or "Q"

```
        string[] namn = new string[5];

        Console.WriteLine("Välkommen");

        int counter = 0;
        string str; 
        for (int i = 0; i < namn.Length; i++ )
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Skriv namn: {0}", counter++);
            str = Console.ReadLine();
            namn[i] = Convert.ToString(str);

        }
```

Comment: Add all related tags like c#

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if namn[i] is either q or Q, like this:

```
    string[] namn = new string[5];

    Console.WriteLine("Välkommen");

    int counter = 0;
    string str; 
    for (int i = 0; i < namn.Length; i++ )
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Skriv namn: {0}", counter++);
        str = Console.ReadLine();
        namn[i] = Convert.ToString(str);
        if (namn[i].Equals("q", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            System.Environment.Exit(1);
    }
```